# set return URL to return to app when transaction is done with paypal

Tags: ios, paypal-adaptive-payments

My app takes user to safari to make payments for physical goods and now I want safari to redirect to my app when payment is done. In paypal Adaptive Payments returnURL parameter is asking for full url like http://www.example.com.  How do I set valid returnURL here to redirect to my app com.payend ?

Comment: how you handle this manoj

Comment: Sorry, I moved from that project shortly after posting this query.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, the App Store Review Guidelines mentions that :

> 11.13
>
> Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions
>   to be used in the App, such as a "buy" button that goes to a web site
>   to purchase a digital book, will be rejected

Comment: thats for digital contents. But here the goods are physical items.

Comment: It's appear to not be a problem for your case. If you want to create your proper url to open your app, I suggest you this link : http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Comment: I know this dude. the problem was paypal needed URL as normal URL format (http://...com). can't give myapp:// or something. there are others ways to handle it with trick. I expected a proper way.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you want. A trick could be to set returnURL to a webpage that redirect the user to the custom url.